# windows 10 black screen before login without cursor, and fast startup mode won't let me go into bios settings

Tags: windows-10, bios, win10-fast-startup

I made a mistakes when I install windows 10:

it told me I need update videos card driver, but I ignored. I reboot to bois, and turn on the fast startup and secure boot, then I save and reboot...

now windows 10 stuck in a black screen without cursor, I have no way to back to bios again.

tried press power button, it turns computer off, and press again, it directly goes to the black screen, seens the fast startup is working prefectly, which is not needed this time. :(

anyway to get around this so I can get in my bios
and get my windows 10 video driver fixed.

Comment: When yoiu reboot, press F2 or DEL and that should get you back into BIOS.

Comment: Or, try F*, which might get you into safe mode

Comment: @Mawg thanks for the F2 trick, why I didn't try this before. and what's the "F*"? I think safe mode is better for me, maybe I can install video card driver there. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant F8 - it boots you into windows, but with no drivers & oprtionally no network.  You will have a very lo-resolution display, but enough to sort out your drivers. I will post an answer.

Comment: yes @Mawg, do post an answer, I will accept it. seems F8 isn't work, it just go to the bios straight away, and what ever i put F5 or any F buttons, it goes to bios, I think it must something wrong with the installation of my win10, I am doing the reinstall, will updated the video card driver before set to fast start up. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deepening on your PC, pressing either F2 or DEL at boot generally gets you into BIOS. You can Google to find which.

You can also try F8 and boot into safe mode. That boots you into windows, but with no drivers & optionally no network. You will have a very lo-resolution display, but enough to sort out your drivers

Answer (score 0):

If you set your bios to fast boot then the possibility exists that your pc is not supporting your keyboard prior to bootup.
Also Windows 10 does not support F8 safemode functionality.
You need to reset your Bios - usually there is a jumper on the motherboard  - 3 pins - 1 and 2 closed = normal operation, 2 and 3 closed = diagnostic mode, no jumper = Bios reset.
Check the mboard, try switching the jumper or removing it - restart your pc.
If it is in diagnostic mode the pc will boot directly into the bios and you can undo the fast boot settings- save and shutdown - replace jumper to normal position and restart, if it resets the bios to the defaults then your screen will not come on until you switch off and replace jumper back to the original position afterwards you should be able to use the F2 key to enter the bios.